# Set FFMPEG input to a mpegts link

Tags: ffmpeg

Can `FFMPEG` take `.mpegts` as an input, i tried with a link like this:

```
ffmpeg  -i  http://website:1010/load/ssssss.mpegts
```

But it gives me `Invalid data found when processing input`, how can i deal with such input ?

Comment: The extension won't matter if the file is valid. And yes, ffmpeg can read MPEG-TS.

Comment: @Mulvya but why `ffmpeg` can't accept it, i can play that link on `vlc` and on `mpv` players, so there are no problem with the file

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Mulvya that was the only output that `ffmpeg` displayed : `http://website:1010/load/ssssss.mpegts: Invalid data found when processing input `